# SQL query including Contains() & group by not working as expected

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, group-by

I have the case below:

- user x category ids in UserInterests table: 1 , 2 , 3
- user y category ids in UserInterests table: 1, 2

The category ids are integer values where (ApplicationUserId,CategoryId) is the composite primary key of mentioned table.
This is the shape of records:

userx  1

userx  2

userx  3

usery  1

usery  2

string interests="1 2"

I want to execute an SQL query that would allow me to retrieve only users having 1 and 2 as interests (not user x).

When I execute the query shown below (knowing that result variable contains the id's of my users)I keep getting user x and user y; I guess it's retrieving the users containing 1&2 but I don't want user x in the result.

```
int count = 2

var result2 = (from t8 in result
               from t9 in _dbContext.UserInterests
               where  t8.id == t9.ApplicationUserId && interests.Contains(t9.CategoryId.ToString())
               group t8 by t8.id into g
               where g.Count() == count
               select g.Key).ToList();
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if you are specific of the interests to be just 1 and 2 but not 3, then try not use Contains("1 2"). Go with explicit Equals("1 2") in your case. But if you are looking for more generic, you need to explain how the values are actually stored in the respective tables. if its plain string like "1 2 3", "1 2", then IMHO i'd suggest you reconsider how you store the values also.

Comment: The category Ids are integers, they could be 1 or 2 or 3 , thus i cannot compare the interest string which contains a bunch of categoryIds to the integer categoryId value to be exactly the same , hope this clarifies & i edited my question. @Ak777

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'd recommend using a join for readability reasons.

```cs
from t8 in result
join t9 in _dbContext.UserInterests
on t8.id equals t9.ApplicationUserId ...
```

Not having two `from` keywords and two `where` keywords in the same query should make things more maintainable.

---

Secondly, I'd change `string interests = "1 2"` to an array: `string[] interests = {"1", "2"}`

---

This is an exclusive query, it's using inclusion and exclusion to get a partial. The best way to achieve it is usually to capture the whole (inclusion), and negate the bad results (exclusion), resulting in a dataset you want.

Another way: `{HasOnlyXCategories} = {AllUserCategoryPairs} - {AllUsersWithCategoriesNotInX}`

Hopefully its clear to see that this new query is much easier to write. We already start with `{AllUserCategoryPairs}` in our join so, we need to write a subquery query that fetches those Users who have categories not in `interests` and then exclude those Users we find.

The following should be what you end up with, or close.

```cs
var result2 = from u in result
              join c in _dbContext.UserInterests
                  on u.id equals c.ApplicationUserId
                  and !interests.Contains(c.CategoryId)
                  into usersBadCategories
              where !usersBadCategories.Any()
              select u;
```

You might have to adjust it a little to fit your context but that should be about the shape of it.

Comment: I edited my question with an example of how the records look in UserInterests table. The categoryId values are integers & could be either 1,or 2,or 3,etc.This field cannot be equal to the interests string. The string simply contains a bunch of categoryIds that the user should have. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: thanks for letting me know, i've re-written my answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks! The exclusion idea has really helped.

Answer (score 0):

There Are multiple ways to achieve what you want, based on the given you have already garbed the users from the db. With this given I do not know about any method to achieve this with single db request.

I've crafted a simple example to be able to validates the result of the query but you can replace the variables with your variables.

> Solution 1 - **Not recommended**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Sample Data
        var allUsers = new List<User>
        {
            new User{Id = 1, Name = "User X"},
            new User{Id = 2, Name = "User Y"},
            new User{Id = 3, Name = "User Z"},
            new User{Id = 4, Name = "User W"}
        };

        var userInterests = new List<UserInterest>
        {
            new UserInterest {FakeId = 1, UserId = 1, CategoryId = 1},
            new UserInterest {FakeId = 2,UserId = 1, CategoryId = 2},
            new UserInterest {FakeId = 3,UserId = 1, CategoryId = 3},
            new UserInterest {FakeId = 4,UserId = 2, CategoryId = 1},
            new UserInterest {FakeId = 5,UserId = 2, CategoryId = 2},
            new UserInterest {FakeId = 6,UserId = 3, CategoryId = 1},
            new UserInterest {FakeId = 7,UserId = 3, CategoryId = 4}
        };

        var interests = "1 2";
        var interestsFilter = interests.Split(" ").ToList();

        var unwantedUserIds = userInterests.Where(q => interestsFilter.All(q2 => q.CategoryId != int.Parse(q2)))
                                            .Select(q => q.UserId).Distinct();

        // Get All users ids that match the filter
        var myUserIds = userInterests.Where(q => unwantedUserIds.All(q2 => q.UserId != q2))
            .Select(q => q.UserId).Distinct();

        // Or Get the users directly 
        var myUsers = allUsers.Join(userInterests,
                                        user => user.Id,
                                        userInterest => userInterest.UserId,
                                        (user, userInterest) => user).Where(q => unwantedUserIds.All(q2 => q.Id != q2)).Distinct();

    }
```

> Solution 2 - **Raw Sql**

Since you are using entity framework and as long as you can achieve results with single db query you go RawSql in case Linq was not able to do it.

[RawSql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)

Comment: Thank you for the options!!